# ConcurrentModificationException error in Rapidminer Studio?

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent, rapidminer

So there is a lab in which I work. We have got Windows server 2012 installed. There are 2 users who connect to the windows server using remote desktop. Rapidminer studio has been installed on windows server so that both users can access it. Both the users are using the same license for rapidminer studio (professional deployment). Now when we both try to run the market basket analysis template on the rapidminer studio at the same time we both get the following error :-

```
Exception: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
Message: null
Stack trace:

  java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)
  java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851)
  com.rapidminer.operator.learner.associations.AssociationRules.getAllConclusionItems(AssociationRules.java:100)
  com.rapidminer.gui.viewer.AssociationRuleFilter.<init>(AssociationRuleFilter.java:86)
  com.rapidminer.gui.viewer.AssociationRuleTableViewer.<init>(AssociationRuleTableViewer.java:61)
  com.rapidminer.gui.renderer.itemsets.AssociationRulesTableRenderer.getVisualizationComponent(AssociationRulesTableRenderer.java:50)
  com.rapidminer.gui.processeditor.results.ResultDisplayTools$1.run(ResultDisplayTools.java:134)
  com.rapidminer.gui.tools.ProgressThread$3.run(ProgressThread.java:552)
  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
  java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Could anyone help me figure out as to why this problem is occuring and how to solve it?

Comment: Yes. There is a bug. But I guess only people at rapidminer can solve that. Therefore and since using java software != java programming => off topic

Comment: can 2 users use the same license for rapidminer studio ? If we use different licenses will the problem be solved ?

Comment: apparently not (but I guess it's not a bug due to license issues). Most `ConcurrentModificationException` aren't even due to concurrency but because of not knowing how to use an `Iterator`

Comment: yeah I guess so... but the problem is rapidminer uses these jar files and and there is no way to openup the code in an editor and change it. I mean i think there has to be another way

Comment: IMO this question is off topic for this site and it will be better to sent a ticket or issue to the company to provide a fix for this.

Comment: As far as I can tell, rapidminer executed your process sucessful but failed in displaying the result. I do not know what the result should be, but maybe a write csv operator could help if the output is an exampleset.